# maximal ideal of PIR

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

PIR means principal ideal ring.This is extended concept of PID, we do not assume integral domain.

Is it true that every nonzero prime ideal is maximal, even in PIR ?
Or, do we need to restrict the condition ?（For example, non nilpotent prime ideal）
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that the product of PIRs is again a PIR. Take any PID $R$ that is not a field, then $R\times 0$ is a prime ideal of $R\times R$, but it is not maximal.

Comment: Thank you for your nice example. What is the nil radical of Z/4Z×Z/4Z ?（maybe the nil radical is not Z/4Z×0, so my conjecture was wrong.）

Comment: Do you know some sufficient condition which makes true the prime ideal give the condtion is maximal？

Comment: In your example the nilradical should be $2Z/4Z\times 2Z/4Z$, but also the ideal $Z/4\times0$ in your example is not prime. But assuming that it is not nilpotent is still not enough, consider $R=\Bbb Z$ for that in my comment above.

Comment: Thank you, aren't there some good condition which makes prime ideal to be maximal?

Comment: I don't know any good conditions, however one thing that one can say is that a PIR as dimension at most 1, so if you have any prime ideal $P$ that is not maximal, then any prime ideal strictly containing $P$ will be maximal, but I don't know how helpful that might be

Comment: @leolo1 why krull dimension of a PIR is at most 1 ?

Comment: If you take any prime $P$ then $R/P$ will be a principal ideal domain hence of dimension $\leq1$. And the dimension of $R$ is just the supremum of the dimensions of the quotiens $R/P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best one can say is that the class of commutative rings for which the nonzero prime ideals are maximal can be classified in two pieces:

1. domains of Krull dimension $1$ (which come in a large variety and can't really be described more simply)
2. rings of Krull dimension $0$ (also called $\pi$-regular rings) which can be characterized as

   1. Rings for which chains of the form $(x)\supseteq (x^2)\supseteq (x^3)\supseteq\ldots$ stabilize for all $x$
   2. $R/N$ is von Neumann regular, where $N$ is the nilradical of $R$.

Principal ideal domains fall under the first item, but since taking finite ring products increases the Krull dimension but preserves the property of being a PIR, you will quickly leave the class (as mentioned in the comments.)

Any Artinian PIR is zero dimensional, though.